# 22.04 mouse click and hold not working

Tags: mouse

I can click or double-click the mouse, but click-hold-drag does nothing.  I can't highlight text to cut and paste, or move windows. I am using X11, not Wayland. I tried 4 different mice.  I tried xdm and Lightdm.  I tried several window managers (I prefer fvwm). I believe this started when I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 from 20.04.